# internet explorer given UI error,on a click input file generate loop and can't stop popupbox

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

[image: bug image into internet explorer]
       i test a cross browser platform for my App but its not work into internet explorer all browser on work well.

```
<label class="myLabel">
<input type="file" id="files" class="form-control" value="" accept="text/plain,text/html">
<a><img src="../../assets/images/filebrowse.png">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Choose Textfile(Only .txt)</a>
</label>


when i choose file from my computer and open it.then its open again.and cancel then again it show.its seems infinite.its stop when i kill browser.
```

[image: solve bug but not completed]

```
i remove label from my html then its work properly.

<input type="file" id="files" class="form-control" value="" accept="text/plain,text/html">
    <a><img src="../../assets/images/filebrowse.png">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Choose Textfile(Only .txt)</a>
```

but it doesn't look like my old output,thats why whole browsers UI on problem.please help to solve internet Explorer browser UI problem.

```
function readTextFile (file, callback, encoding) {
    var e;
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener('load', function (e) {
        callback(this.result);
    });
    if (encoding) reader.readAsText(file, encoding);
    else reader.readAsText(file);

}

 function fileChosen(input, output) {

    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        readTextFile(
            input.files[0],
            function (str) {
                output.value = str;

                var name=input.files[0];
                 console.log(name);
            },
        "");

    }

}
$('#files').on('change', function () {
    fileChosen(this, document.getElementById('result'));
});
```

this is my ts file. i am using Angular2.

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce the problem with IE11. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/oc224y52/). No matter if I choose a .txt file or press cancel, the file dialog does not pop up again. So, which version of IE are you using? Are there factors at play you're not showing here, such as JavaScript routines for file handling? Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue? And last but not least, do you really need the <a>?

Comment: hello @MrLister thank you for your response.i am using Angular 2 with typescript. now my IE version is IE11. i deploy website   http://scantolearn.com ,

Comment: its work on whole web browser but only problem in IE.